# Sqlitelarge database for phone

Tags: android

I have 250k records using database. I have already written code for retrieval but it takes 2 min but I want to retrieve the data in seconds it is difficult for me to retrieve.

Comment: Trying to optimizing your database structure. I suggest you use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try optimizing your query. You may also use indexes for faster querying.

Comment: please tell how to do index for quering